# Create a method to add key value pairs to a hash

Tags: methods, hash, ruby-1.9.3

Getting a wrong number of arguments error (1 for 2) when trying to create a simple method to add key value pairs to a hash. Using ruby 1.9.3.

```
@roommates = {}  # => {}

def dic(per, desc)   # ~> ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)

@roommates[per] = desc
end

p dic("beni" => "messy")
```

---

```
ArgumentError wrong number of arguments (1 for 2)
/Users/mwsage/Desktop/programs/p1weekend/dictionary.rb:13:in `dic'
/Users/mwsage/Desktop/programs/p1weekend/dictionary.rb:21:in `<main>'
```

Also tried using @roommates.store(person, definition)

Feel like I have tried every combination of parameters (1 or 2) as signs or strings, when defining the method and when trying to send the arguments.

The goal of this is to simply be able to add roommates and a description, and must be in a hash.

Please help with this very simple problem that is making me crazy.

Answer (score 0):

It thinks you are trying to pass a key, value pair (like when initializing a Hash).

Try this instead and it will think you have two arguments:

```
p dic("beni", "messy")
```